# Increment Value of Span only once

Tags: jquery, increment

So I have an ajax which goes something like this:

```
$('.clike').each(function(){
$(this).on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var commentLike = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "//link",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        statusCode: {
            200: function () {
                console.log('worked! '+commentLike);

                var newValue = parseInt($(".clikebadge"+commentLike).text(), 10) + 1;

                $(".clikebadge"+commentLike).text(newValue);
            }
        },

    });
});
});
```

So my question here is with this part.

```
var newValue = parseInt($(".clikebadge"+commentLike).text(), 10) + 1;

$(".clikebadge"+commentLike).text(newValue);
```

So every time I click the like button, it gives a status 200. But I do not want to keep incrementing the value of the span. It does work. I mean it does increment. But I don't want it to keep on incrementing. I want it to increment only once and stop. I want to increment only once. Right now it keeps on going. How can I do this with JQuery.

I know there is a JQuery `once.('click')` but I don't see how I could use that in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by saving the state. (In the example in `data-incremented`)

A better way to do this is to return `true` or `false` by your JSON if the like has been placed by the user already.

```js
$('.clike').each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var commentLike = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
      dataType: "JSON",
      cache: false,
      statusCode: {
        200: function() {
          console.log('worked! ' + commentLike);
          
          var $badge = $(".clikebadge[data-for-id=" + commentLike + "]");
          if ($badge.data('incremented') !== 1) {
            console.log( 'incrementing' );

            var newValue = parseInt($badge.text(), 10) + 1;
            $badge.text(newValue);

            // save increment
            $badge.data('incremented', 1);
          }
        }
      },

    });
  });
});
```

```css
.clikebadge {
  background-color: #7C7;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="clike" data-id="99" value="Click me!" />
<span class="clikebadge" data-for-id="99">1</span>
```

Comment: A million +1's If only that was possible. One question. On this line `$badge.data('incremented') !== 1` What is `incremented`. Are we creating a new state called incremented? And if it is 0 (!1), then return 'incrementing'. Correct?

Comment: @PICKAB00 Its the jQuery way to add `data-incremented="1"` to the element. If its not `1` it has never been set :) Go ahead if you got further questions! - so its basically just a name

Comment: Ok got it. So basically it is just adding a data-incremented attribute to the span tag and if the value is ! Equal 1, then do the incremental to span. And when the incremental is done once, then the data-incremented attr becomes 1 and thus, it has an incremented state. Nice :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.clike').each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var commentLike = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
      dataType: "JSON",
      cache: false,
      statusCode: {
        200: function() {
          console.log('worked! ' + commentLike);
          
          var $badge = $(".clikebadge[data-for-id=" + commentLike + "]");
          if ($badge.data('incremented') !== 1) {
            console.log( 'incrementing' );

            var newValue = parseInt($badge.text(), 10) + 1;
            $badge.text(newValue);

            // save increment
            $badge.data('incremented', 1);
          }
        }
      },

    });
  });
});
```

```css
.clikebadge {
  background-color: #7C7;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="clike" data-id="99" value="Click me!" />
<span class="clikebadge" data-for-id="99">1</span>
```